# Communication between asp.net website and Kubernetes/docker microservices in Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, docker, kubernetes

We're planning an architecture where asp.net websites must communicate with microservices.
The plan is to hos this in Azure, with the Website being an Azure ASP.NET Website and the microservices in Kubernetes/docker containers.
I was thinking kubenet was the way to go, so that a number of microservice instances could be spawned on demand without the need for the website to know about this, but it seems like VM-Kubernetes connectivity is not supported unless initiated by the Pod, or am I misunderstanding something?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-network#azure-virtual-networks

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you want to achieve and which tools you want to use? If I understand correctly you want to have cluster on azure with a website, additionally in this cluster you have few or your microservices which should be able to communicate with your website? Or where is the website and where are the microservices?

Comment: @Jakub the website should be hosted in Azure, on the same Azure virtual network as the Kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add VM in the same Virtual Network as Kubernetes Cluster. And provide private Ip to Kubernetes services using

annotation "service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
and VM So they can communicate with each other.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!
I think this is exactly what we need.